# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject running outside of Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, json, netbeans

Similar questions have been asked here about this error, but I have tried most of the solutions and still get the same error message.  I'm using json-simple library in my java app.  I have included the json-simple-1.1.1.jar file in my library. Running through Netbeans works perfectly.  When I try running it through the command line "java -jar " I get the following error. Even "java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar -jar  still give the same error.

```
nullException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
    at gui.keo_synopticx.jb_save_configMouseClicked(keo_synopticx.java:5318)
    at gui.keo_synopticx.access$6000(keo_synopticx.java:49)
    at gui.keo_synopticx$60.mouseClicked(keo_synopticx.java:3358)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

I may be missing a dependency for json-simple-1.1.1? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Manually adding json-simple-1.1.1.jar to the Class-Path in the manifest.mf still creates the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

The org/json/simple/JSONObject class is definitely in the jar file.

The only reason for the problem I can think of is that you did not specify the jar file path, and that the jar is not in the same directory as your execution directory.

Comment: exactly, the main classpath configuration is given by netbeans in its config file.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you should precise your classpath on the terminal:

syntaxe:

```
java -classpath <your_archive.jar> [<package>.]<Class_name>
```

don't forget the package if the class belongs to one.